# will future versions of julia be backward compatible

Tags: julia

Not sure if this is the right forum (and if so, point out to me and I will delete this post!).

I had been evaluating languages to replace a existing code written in R that has around 4k-5k lines(and used for live trading), primarily to get speed and I liked Julia (v0.2.0) - not only for its speed, but also because the language is easy to learn.

I would like to initiate a project to rewrite the existing R code in Julia, but since it can be a major exercise for me, I wanted to ask if there **is any information available anywhere whether the future releases of Julia will be largely backward compatible with Julia v0.2.0**?

For example, one issue I faced earlier with Python was that v3.0 onwards are not quite backward compatible with v2.7, and v2.5 codes don't often work on v2.6, v2.6 codes don't often work on v2.7, requiring significant rewrites because you have to carefully evaluate where the old code broke (and was almost always better to rewrite the code from fresh). I want to avoid the same issue with Julia.

Comment: Who knows about the future?

Comment: Python people, I think. At least, they can import things from there

Comment: I don't want to thread-jack, but re: Python-- "2.5 codes don't often work on v2.6, v2.6 codes don't often work on v2.7": that's awfully rare.  Respectfully, I find it impossible to believe that it was almost always better to rewrite a 2.[56] code from scratch to get it to run in 2.7.

Comment: @DSM, I actually love Python and Python is 2nd choice to rewrite my codes. Sadly, my experience was true partly because at that time the Python codes were co-written with a colleague who was far more experienced Python user and he ended-up writing classes for almost every small thing and wrote long codes with elaborate loggers, constructors and huge number of functions for every tiny thing within a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Dirk is right that anything is on the table for changing up to version 1.0, we do have some assurances about compatibility:

- There is a `release-0.2` branch that will contain only bug-fixes, so if you write code for Julia 0.2, it will continue to work on that branch
- We try very hard to deprecate APIs that we change, rather than just yanking them out from under you. This means that your code will keep working, but you will get a warning telling you the new way to do something.

There have been very few basic syntax changes in the past year, and I don't really foresee any big ones. Most of the changes that still need to happen are standard library API changes.

Comment: thanks. keep up the great work on Julia. best rdgs

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I clarified a little.  And in general, changes are good yet API changes are bad, so we all walk this delicate balance.

Comment: @Stefan, do have an approximate time frame in mind for Julia v1.0 ?

Comment: It's a very rough guess, but late 2014 seems possible.

Answer (score 1):

"Maybe" but probably not.

Goals for the 0.3 to 1.0 transition are (among other things) to get all breaking changes out of the way.

In other words, between now and 1.0 changes are to be expected.